# PostScript operators and Reverse Polish Notation for plotting using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I know that the PSTricks packages for plotting, `pst-plot` and `pst-3dplot`, use PostScript operators and [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). Is there a comprehensive list of all the operators available, with a guide on such notation?

Comment: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=PS/refs there you'll find two small references

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find them in a manual of PostScript language.

See [*PostScript Language Reference, third edition*](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf)

And for convinience, *The PostScript Language Tutorial and Cookbook* and *PostScript Language Program Design* are easier to read. You can find them at [Adobe PostScript SDK Archive](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/ps/sdk/index_archive.html)

---

Maybe you have known that, `PSTricks` can also use infix expression to plot functions, with help of `algebraic=true`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\psset{algebraic=true}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-1.5)(4,1.5)
\psaxes(0,0)(-3.5,-1.5)(3.5,1.5)
\psplot[linecolor=blue]{-3.14}{3.14}{sin(x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Supported functions:

> `+` `-` `*` `/` `^`
>   sin, cos, tan, acos, asin (in radians)
>   log, ln
>   ceiling, floor, truncate, round, sqrt, abs, fact (for the factorial)
>   Sum (for building sums)
>   IfTE (for an easy case structure)

See manual [`pst-news10`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pst-news10.pdf) for details.

Comment: +1 The PS operators wont be listed by `pstricks` itself.

Comment: What do you mean with "wont be listed"?

Answer (score 3):

The language reference is a bit heavyweight. This is the reference I use: [Alphabetic list of PostScript commands](http://atrey.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~milanek/PostScript/Reference/REF.html). Comprehensive, yet browsable. In case that reference goes away, one can likely find a mirror searching for page titles containing [Postscript Level 2](http://google.com/search?q=intitle%3A%22postscript%20level%202%22).